# Row value into column headings

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a `readings` table. It is defined as:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 device     | character varying(25)       |           | not null |
 type       | character varying(25)       |           | not null |
 value      | numeric                     |           | not null |
```

It has data such as:

```
     created_at      |  device   |    type     |    value
---------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------
 2021-03-16 07:46:47 | 465125783 | temperature |        36.5
 2021-03-16 07:51:48 | 465125783 | temperature | 36.40000153
 2021-03-16 07:52:47 | 465125783 | temperature | 36.40000153
 2021-03-16 07:53:47 | 465125783 | temperature | 36.29999924
 2021-03-24 17:53:47 | 123456789 | pressure    |          79
 2021-03-24 17:54:48 | 123456789 | pressure    |          77
 2021-03-28 05:38:48 | 123456789 | flow        |          12
 2021-03-28 05:45:48 | 123456789 | flow        |          14
 2021-03-28 05:49:47 | 123456789 | pressure    |          65
 2021-03-28 05:50:47 | 123456789 | flow        |          32
 2021-03-28 05:51:47 | 123456789 | flow        |          40
```

I am trying to write a query where for a specified device, I make each unique value in `type` become a heading and work out a **daily average** for the `value` over **the past two weeks only** (as time-period from `now()`).

So basically, I pass my query the device id, and get:

```
   date     |  device   | pressure | flow
------------+-----------+----------+-------
 2021-03-28 | 123456789 | 65       | 24.5
 2021-03-24 | 123456789 | 78       | 0
```

Notice the *desc sort* on date and time information is no longer needed, only the date is required.

I have created a [db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMkv7GdsJGUyFudpFDVXkC/0). The concept of getting column headings from rows is not something I have done before.

Comment: `2021-03-28 | 123456789`, why does this date-device appear twice in your example result, do you need 1 row for `flow` & a separate row for `pressure`?

Comment: Good catch @HaleemurAli, I'll update. One row is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses `FILTER`:

```
select created_at::date, device,
       avg(value) filter (where type = 'pressure') as pressure,
       avg(value) filter (where type = 'flow') as flow
from readings
group by created_at::date, device;
```

Note:  This represents missing values as `NULL` rather than `0`, which makes sense to me.  You can use `COALESCE()` if you want `0`.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMkv7GdsJGUyFudpFDVXkC/1) is the db-fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff, I think you're forgetting to click update on db-fiddle, your link takes me to my original db-fiddle link, so I see no change. Also, with this approach, I must know all my `type` values before hand? Is there a way I can make that dynamic?

Comment: @J86 . . . Dynamic requires dynamic SQL, I think.